# Can i make a stepper motor stop at 120° increments?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, 12v

I have another project, but being much less than a beginner with programming chips I am coming to you fine people for help.

The basic premise is that I want a motor to turn within a full 360° cycle but stop at precisely 120° with a press of a single button. So in simple terms I'd like :

Button press
120° turn, stop and hold
Button press
120° turn, stop and hold
Button Press 
120° turn, stop and hold

and on and on...

Could someone please explain to me in layman's terms how I can do this as it is essential to my project.

Many, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the number of steps per revolution of the motor, divide that by three, and go that many steps.

Comment: This is an engineering site, and in engineering nothing is perfect, and everything has tolerances. So what are your tolerances? Specifically, just exactly how precise does your 120 degree step have to be? +/- 10 degrees? 5 degrees? 1 degree? 0.1 degree? .001 degree? Please explain your requirements in enough detail to justify your tolerance.

Comment: Determine current position with an optical encoder, to control the motor.

Answer (score 2):

You are limited by the resolution of the motor (and driver, if the latter is a micro stepping type).

For example if you have a 1.8 degree motor and a driver that does not micro step then you would want to move 66.67 steps to have it rotate 120 angular degrees. Since that's not possible, one approach would be to step 67, then 66, then 67. That way there would be a slight error in the positions but it would not accumulate- 300 increments would result in exactly 100 rotations of the motor shaft.

The same issues will arise with a micro-stepping drive, but with smaller errors.

You have a choice with the hold-  if you keep the motor energized you'll have high holding torque, but it will consume more power than if you de-energize the motor.

Edit: Note that the motor itself will have some accuracy, with no load and as you approach the holding torque the error will increase to something like half a step. So perhaps +/-10%~30% of one step. If you're using a 7.5 degree motor and it's unloaded the error might be +/-0.8 degree. If you are off by 1/3 of a 1.8 degree step and it's unloaded the error might similar (a bit less). At heavy loading the the finer steps will be considerably more accurate. [Here](https://www.anaheimautomation.com/manuals/stepper/L010968%20-%20TSM57-075%20Series%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf) is a more detailed datasheet of a typical motor.

Note: I more-or-less ignored your statement of 'exactly' but nothing is really exact in engineering. If you want close to the best accuracy achievable you could use a servo with a good encoder (Renishaw or whatever) and you could get to maybe +/- 1 arc second using feedback from the encoder, but it would cost about as much as an automobile.

Comment: Note there are also 48-step (7.5 degree) motors where you could step 16 steps for 120 degrees.

Comment: Ok so I've found this [link](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-Philips-12V-2W-Unipolar-7-5-Degree-Stepper-Motor-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi-/121362990635) what will I need to drive it and how would i programme it to rotate to three 120° increments?